# Бразды правления

Tags: склонение

Бразды правления - так говорят об ответственности, власти.
Как я понимаю, бразды - то же самое, что вожжи, так? Но как-то в кроссворде это слово попалось в единственном числе - "бразда". И я задумалась: а как, собственно, правильно будет звучать единственное число? Вожжи - вожжа, это понятно. А вот бразды?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-тут не вяжется. Вожжи они вожжами, а удила удилами. 
В упряжи для каждой детали и так есть свое название. Узда целый набор ремней и приспособ, но простейшая, это просто петля.

И такая простейшая узда - поводья, а поводья БЕРУТ  и держат в руках, когда лошадь ведут. Надевают просто на шею. Бразды это беру+узда, взял под уздцы. Наиболее близкое смысловое сочетание корней. Тогда борозда - это то, что получается при пахоте и одновременным управлением лошадью при помощи узды. А езда - просто управление лошадью.
Это подтверждается при переводе на другие языки - бразды-поводья.

Comment: Кстати, любой конник скажет, что не узда, а уздечка)))

Comment: Это сейчас конник скажет, вроде как просторечие. Мой дедушка учил меня, пацана, "Узду натягивай, удила держи!"

Answer (score 1):

По выражению, конечно, кажется, что бразды — это те же вожжи, но словарь Даля говорит, что "удила". Единственное число — "бразда" или более древнее слово "брозда".

Answer (score 1):

> *...словарь Даля говорит, что "удила".*

*БРАЗДЫ* -- не только удила.

> ***БРАЗДЫ** -- конские удила, **узда.** В рус. языке XI–XVII вв. изв. **бръзда, бьрзда, бъздра** «удила,
> **уздечка, уздцы**».*
>
> https://books.google.ru/books?id=GZ2KAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&dq=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=68XYVMuDNuWgyAPEn4DoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false

А вот за ***уздцы*** (поводья около *удил*) действительно можно вести. И не только коня…

Comment: У Даля — только.

Comment: В русском языке утвердилась форма "вести под уздцы".

Comment: ***У Даля — только*** 

Вполне достаточно одного Даля.

Comment: Варяг-91: В русском языке утвердилась форма "вести под уздцы".=== Не только "под". См.:

В ворота за уздцы вводил лошадей Пантелей Прокофьевич.
[Шолохов Михаил Александрович
Тихий Дон. Том 2  
http://www.libok.net/writer/2697/kniga/8217/sholohov_mihail_aleksandrovich/tihiy_don_tom_2/read/13 ]